# How to open new tab in java wicket using code

Tags: java, wicket

I have to validate my code first after clicking on button then need to open new page with new tab in wicket.
I already used target= "_blank" option but it did't work for me.

Comment: I added a button then clicking on them there is pop-up comes and after hitting on yes i have to open new page on different tab, But it opens on same page.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the confirmation, you can utilize PopupSettings to open another page on a different tab:

```
PopupSettings settings = new PopupSettings();
settings.setTarget(String.format("'%s'", urlFor(AnotherPage.class, null)));
ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavaScript(settings.getPopupJavaScript());
```

Update:
It's up to the browser though, whether a new window or a new tab is opened:

[Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: No this is not working this is my code here, i'm using setResponsePage() method, like below 
                  setResponsePage(new AddNewPriceOptionPage(revenueCriteria, ruleList, this.getPage().getPageReference()));

Comment: Actually above solution open new pop-up but i want to open new tab on same browser.

Comment: yes this true, But sorry i want to use setResponcePage() method  and in that class object having some attributes like ,
 List<ImportCashflowRule> ruleList = ((ArrayList<ImportCashflowRule>) group.getModelObject());
                  getRevenueCriteria(ruleList, revenueCriteria, actieTextField.getValue());
                  setResponsePage(new AddNewPriceOptionPage(revenueCriteria, ruleList, this.getPage().getPageReference()));
so i can't use popupSetting.